# Why does a comparator changes its state when I touch any node at the input?

Tags: operational-amplifier, noise, comparator

I'm connecting LM339 as a comparator and it works well but it becomes very sensitive when the input voltage(at the +ve input) is near to the reference voltage(at the -ve input), It changes its output state whenever i touch any of the inputs (Even with a multimeter lead).

Is that noise? if yes, what kind of noise is that? and is it avoidable?

Comment: Add hysteresis.

Comment: Noise, and the fact you just added capacitance resistance and inductance to the circuit you are measuring, especially if the input signal is from a high impedance source.

Comment: @MattYoung I added 1M resistor but nothing changed, It still changes state when i touch the + or the - terminal.

Comment: Your comparator's input circuit is very high impedance and can be disturbed by the high impedance loads of your finger or the meter. We can't do much more unless you edit your question and post your circuit, though - running conversations through comments is not how the site works.question

Comment: @Trevor Actually the input is a DC voltage taken from a simple voltage divider and a potentiometer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the old joke says "If it hurts don't do it".

The noise you are picking up is probably from 60Hz interference and is normal. You can also pick up AM radio stations if there any strong ones nearby.

Unless it is causing a problem for normal operation ignore it. If it is a problem then you may need to shield the circuit inside a grounded metal case. Having lower impedances in your circuit can also help but as you have shown you may need much lower than 1 megohm.  I usually design for resistances in the 10K region.

If the pickup is predominantly high frequency such as from an AM radio station a series resistor can help.  Together with the input capacitance of the device it forms a low pass filter to filter out the noise.  The effect can be enhanced by adding a parallel capacitor.

Have you ever tried putting your finger on the input to an amplifier and heard a loud buzzing from the speaker - that is the same thing.  If you put your finger on the input to a scope you can usually see many volts of 60/50Hz pickup as well.

Comment: I was ignoring series resistors at the input that are specified in the datasheet. I added 10k ohm at the inverting inverting input and 10k hystresis resistor and it works just fine.

[The circuit here](http://i.imgur.com/0UivUnp.jpg)

What is the purpose of these resistors though?

Comment: Ok i checked up the datasheet again and it seems that R2 and Rref set the hystresis voltage. but i still don't know what is the purporse of R3.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the effect of R3.  What are you feeding the input form?

Comment: The input is taken from a simple resistor potentiometer divider.

Comment: If the potentiometer used lower value resistance and you keep the wires short it will reduce the chance of pickup. Although if it is not causing problems during normal usage then ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

Noise, and the fact you just added capacitance resistance and inductance to the circuit you are measuring, especially if the input signal is from a high impedance source.

Is it avoidable. That depends on whether making it go away so you can use your measurement device affects the functionality of your circuit and how important it is to allow someone to take that measurement on the active model.

Adding circuitry so you can test the unit actually reduces the reliability of the system, so you need to justify the addition carefully.

If it is critical to measure it, for example to set  some reference. Then it is prudent to put the signal through a buffer so it has a low impedance source at the measurement point.